# Why Does this sed command work in terminal but not in bash ".sh" script

Tags: bash, sed, environment-variables

Sorry this seems to be asked a lot in various different ways but none have helped me understand why this isn't working.

If I run the following:

```
sed -i".bak" "s:$PRELOADER_BASH::" ~/.bashrc
```

in the terminal, it works. However I want to run it as part of a sh script, when I do this I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
```

Can someone please explain to me why it is doing this?

Environment variable PRELOADER_BASH is:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/mylib1.so /usr/lib/mylib2.so
```

The spaces and slashes caused me early problems.

Comment: Your export variable is LD_PRELOAD, however in the sed command  it is PRELOADER_BASH ?

Comment: @Guru The OP has mentioned that the export line is the *contents of PRELOADER_BASH*

Comment: Add a `set -x` in your sh script.  That'll echo every command as bash sees it (with variables expanded) .. may show something useful.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you run your script using `bash script.sh` instead of `./script.sh`?

Comment: Is PRELOADER_BASH variable exported?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the problem.  In addition to the requests from eduffy and Shawn, could you supply us with the relevant lines from your .bashrc (e.g. the LD_PRELOAD line, the line where PRELOADER_BASH is defined/exported).  Are you running script.sh using bash or sh? Does it help if you wrap the variable in braces, i.e. "s:${PRELOADER_BASH}::"

Comment: the set -x thing is really useful i will definitely be using that in the future thank you eduffy! I actually got this working a few minutes using an older version of the file and have worked out what it was, will post soon

Answer (score 0):

Your variable PRELOADER_BASH is known to the shell script? You have to export it to have access to it in sub shells (e.g. in shell scripts).

Define your variable like that:

```
export PRELOADER_BASH="export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/mylib1.so /usr/lib/mylib2.so"
```

Then run your shell script and it will work. It will replace all occurences of `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/mylib1.so /usr/lib/mylib2.so` in your ~/.bashrc file with nothing (i.e. delete it).

**Explanation**

On the command line you had probably defined your variable like that:

```
PRELOADER_BASH="export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/mylib1.so /usr/lib/mylib2.so"
```

This makes it available in the current shell, but not in sub shells. Therefore you need to use `export`.

Instead of exporting you can also define your variable in the shell script.

Comment: sorry i should have specified for the command line version I used export but i also have it set in the bashrc via = . I have echo'd it in the past to make sure its correct

I believe its actually something to do with the way it expands this variable...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out i was being a bit over cautious and silly as i didnt post the exact script code here, earlier on in the bash files life cycle when trying to solve the spaces and /'s issue I was exporting PRELOADER_BASH in the following way:

```
PRELOADER_BASH='export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libopenvg.so /usr/lib/libinterposer.so"'
```

which is actually what caused the error! the best way was to do the following:

```
PRELOADER_BASH="export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libopenvg.so /usr/lib/libinterposer.so"
```

in hindsight its really stupid because with my "over-done" preloader bash setting it was probably expanding it directly to:

```
sed -i".bak" "s:'export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libopenvg.so /usr/lib/libinterposer.so"'::" ~/.bashrc
```

so the sed command would have indeed have a " unterminated `s' command "

sed -i".bak" **"** s:'export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libopenvg.so /usr/lib/libinterposer.so **"**'::" ~/.bashrc

very sorry to waste peoples time on this, clearly I need a cup of coffee!